# Kubernetes : dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, kops

I've launched kubernetes cluster using kops. It was working find and I started facing the following problem:

```
kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

How do i solve this?
It looks like kubernetes-apiserver is not running, How do i get this working?

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx:1.10.0
error: failed to discover supported resources: Get http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1beta1?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kubernetes uses a `$KUBECONFIG` file for connecting to clusters. It may be when provisioning your kops cluster, it didn't write the file correctly. I can't be sure as you haven't provided enough info.

Assuming this is the issue, and you only have a single cluster, it can be resolved like so:

```
# Find your cluster name
kops get clusters
# set the clustername as a var
clustername=<clustername>
# export the KUBECONFIG variable, which kubectl uses to find the kubeconfig file
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/${clustername}
# download the kubeconfig file locally using kops
kops export kubecfg --name ${clustername} --config=~$KUBECONFIG
```

You can find more information about the `KUBECONFIG` file [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Answer (score 4):

you have to start `minikube` before using `kubectl`
I had the same issue but mine was because `minikube` was not running

Comment: The question is about kubernetes cluster deployed using cops not minikube.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command before the kubectl command

gcloud container clusters get-credentials  --zone=us-central1

Comment: The question is about clusters deployed with Kops, not GKE.